# How to pass `undefined` value to an optional argument in storybook?

Tags: typescript, storybook

I'm making a storybook for a component that has prop types

```
value?: number;
fallbackText?: string;
```

and the way it shows can be simplified to

```
if (props.value === undefined && props.fallbackText)
    return <InnerComponent value={props.fallbackText} {...otherProps} />
return  <InnerComponent value={props.value} {...otherProps} />;
```

In words, it shows `value`, if that is `undefined` it shows `fallbackText` instead. I want this behavior in the storybook, preferably in a single story.

Now, I'm making storybook but I'm struggling with defining the `argTypes` in a way that would allow me to set `value` to either `undefined` or `number`. This is what I have so far:

```
argTypes: {
    value: { control: 'number' },
    fallbackText: { control: 'text' }
},
args: {
    value: 100,
    fallbackText: undefined
}
```

The problem is that if I delete the number, which I'd expect to give `undefined` value, it just highlights the field in red and doesn't pass the `undefined` value, like so:
[image]

Is there any addon or control option that would allow me to pass a `number | undefined` as a value? Preferably without altering the component itself of course.

Comment: Maybe you could use [conditional controls](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/controls#conditional-controls) and only show the number field if you enable it.

Comment: Well yes, but I was hoping to avoid having extra controls that aren't props.